# SP url - Problem with alias

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio, url, 401

I have a problem when using an alias to access my Sharepoint (2013) site through code.

I want to retrieve a document from a SharePoint library.

In my browser address bar I can type either :
http://myserver.domain:port/mylibrary/mydocument.xlsx
http://myAliasTotheSiteCollection/mylibrary/mydocument.xlsx

Both are OK.

But if I want to access the same file through code, the link with the alias does not work.

Here is the code:

```
strLink= "http://myserver.domain:port/mylibrary/mydocument.xlsx";
System.Net.WebClient wcVar = new System.Net.WebClient();
wcVar.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(myLogin, myPwd, myEnvironnement);
wcVar.DownloadFile(strLink, strDestination);
```

=> **OK**

```
strLink= "http://myAliasTotheSiteCollection/mylibrary/mydocument.xlsx";
System.Net.WebClient wcVar = new System.Net.WebClient();
wcVar.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(myLogin, myPwd, myEnvironnement);
wcVar.DownloadFile(strLink, strDestination);
```

=> **ERROR 401 Unauthorized**

How can I do to use the alias instead of the "hard coded" address ?

Thank you